# ("#panel").is is not a function error Jquery

Tags: jquery

Ive no idea why this throws back an error

```
        if((("#panel").is(':visible') && elm.length==0)||((("#panel").is(':hidden') && elm.length>0))){
            showSubMenu()
        }
```

("#panel").is is not a function ???

Could someone explain to me the logic of why this causes an error ? so that I dont repeat ?

Comment: facepalm = you're missing the $ --> $("#panel")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the jQuery object $, try this:

```
 if(($("#panel").is(':visible') && elm.length==0)||(($("#panel").is(':hidden') && elm.length>0))){
        showSubMenu()
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

`"#panel"` is a string.
Strings have no `.is()` method.

You probably want to call `$` to make a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

try it with the jQuery function notation:

```
if(($("#panel").is(':visible') && elm.length==0)||((("#panel").is(':hidden') && elm.length>0))){
            showSubMenu()
        }
```

Comment: yeah I realized that as soon as I wrote it

Comment: $ is just a place holder for Jquery object.

Comment: `$` is a **function**.  `jQuery` refers to the same function.

Comment: @SLaks in javascript a function is same as object.isn't it?

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili: A function is a kind of object.  However, `$` is not a placeholder.

Comment: isn't that the n-etiquette equivalent to slapping someone with your glove?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the $ sign;

Try

```
if(($("#panel").is(':visible') && elm.length==0)||((("#panel").is(':hidden') && elm.length>0))){
            showSubMenu()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the jQuery-function - call (most used in form of `$`) in front of your selector

```
$('#panel').is(':visible')
```

Without this, `'#panel'` will just be a string rather than a jQuery-element. jQuery-elements then let you call functions like `.is` on them, which a `String` - Object simply does not have, that's why you get that error.